# Rename sheets using different file

Tags: excel, vba

Can someone give idea how can I rename the sheet name using different excel file.

[image: My Main File]

This is my main file, using this file I can rename the file name. Renaming the file name is okay. But I don't know how can use that path and file name in `Column B` to rename it's sheet name.

I can rename the sheet name using this code:

```
Sheets(1).Name = "New Name"
```

But I can apply that code on it's own workbook.

How can I use the `column B` file path and name to rename the sheet name base on the `column B` value.

Comment: Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/name-statement) out.

Comment: @JvdV I think that link refers to renaming file name. My problem is I need to rename the sheet name base on the `Column B` file path and name. For ex. I have this path and name `C:\Test\Test.xlsx` in `Column B` I need to rename the sheet name of `C:\Test\Test.xlsx` to what value in `Column C`.

Comment: To clarify: you want to change the name of `Sheet(1)` in each of the files listed to the name in `Column B`?

Comment: @Zac Yes! That's what I want.

Comment: Well that was not clear for me from your question. Excuse me then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please find attached a code that should suit your requirements. I tested it and worked for me. It edits the name of the first sheet of the file the adress  in each cell in column b refers to (starting from the third row) to the value in column c.

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    Dim Pat As String
    Dim ShName As String

    Set wsh = Sheets("sheet1") 'rename this with the name of the sheet in your screenshot

    For i = 3 To wsh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Pat = wsh.Cells(i, 2).Value            'get Path name from column B (2)
        ShName = wsh.Cells(i, 3).Value         'get Name from Column C (3)
        Workbooks.Open(Pat).Sheets(1).Name = ShName 'open workbook to change name of sheet
        ActiveWorkbook.Close saveChanges:=True  'close workbook, skip dialog (save)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! It works, I've just edited some of the code to fit to my existing code.